# Add Subdomain to Wordpress main site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So my main domain is build on the wordpress platform. I have build a custom website which is NOT build on a wordpress platform. All I am trying to do is host the site I build on a subdomain. Thus it should look like this:

`www.subsomain.maindomain.com`

I have uploaded my files to the `subdomain` folder and all is working.

**MY PROBLEM**

My site works fine when entering `subdomain.maindomain.com` i.e. without the `www` version.

However as soon as I try to redirect my site to www.`subdomain.maindomain.com` I get a DNS SERVER NOT FOUND error.

So my NON www version works but when I try to run the WWW version it does not work.

What I have done.

1. Redirect the subdomain to www version in Cpanel (didnt work)
2. Change the.htaccess file, tried multiple tweaks and changes (didnt work)
3. **I called godaddy the agent told me because the main site runs on wordpress platform I would need to go into the mainsites wordpress database and make changes there for the www version of subdoman to work...? (is this correct, it doesnt make sese to me..?)**

Here is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect to another domain: example.com.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

All I want to do is **redirect my subdomain to www version** Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because www.subsomain.maindomain.com doesn't exist. You have to add a CNAME record in your zone subsomain.maindomain.com the same way you've added the host subdomain to maindomain.com.